# Is the bleeder valve on top of the air separator above the expansion tank supposed to stay open?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, valve, boiler

I have a Navien hot water heater, it looses pressure slowly and external low water light comes on.  I noticed the bleeder valve on top of the air separator is closed.  If I open it, air comes out high pressure, but I was afraid to leave it open.

Is this supposed to be open or closed?

[image: bleeder valve, air separator, expansion tank]

Comment: Which model, specifically? Have you looked for an owners/instruction/installation manual online? I'm pretty sure that would specify.